# Join PropertyInfo[] with iEnumerable<T> where every PropertyInfo.Name equals any T.variableContent

Tags: linq, join, reflection, ienumerable

Im working with C# reflection and couldn't find a way to solve this.

I want to join a list of PropertyInfos where the listed field names matches contents in a variable of any element of T.

It's kinda complex to explain, but I hope you understand.

Example:

```
var listProperties = objetoAtual.GetType().GetProperties().Join(listaRegistros, prop => prop.Name, reg => reg.A_Campo_Registro, ??????)

foreach (PropertyInfo property in listProperties)
{
  lb_propName = property.Name;
}
```

I tried to create a new PropertyInfo at TResult parameter, but PropertyInfo is abstract.
I need to create a custom class that inherit PropertyInfo and use it?

Thanks

Comment: It might be easier for us to understand if you tell us the problem you're trying to solve, and then we can work backward into the solution.

Comment: Im using reflection to read dynamically an entire table information (A), plus I have the current table register infos in another variable (B). I want to mix every property name of the table (A) that appears in the stored properties names in the table (B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can project to an anonymous type (having the properties you are interested in) instead of PropertyInfo:

```
var properties = objetoAtual.GetType().GetProperties().Join(listaRegistros, 
                              prop => prop.Name, 
                              reg => reg.A_Campo_Registro, 
                              (prop, reg) => new { Name = prop.Name });

foreach (var property in properties)
{
   lb_propName = property.Name;
}
```